# Should dll developed as Nuget be placed in separate repository for internal company use?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

I was developing an ASP.Net Core Web Api together with dlls specyfic to the domain. I have also developed a dll which turned out to be the one that can be shared across organization as NuGet dll. I created that dll in the same solution where i have my AspNet Core app. In consequence each time I run a build, version of this Nuget is bumbed up even if no changes were made to that dll.

I have 2 questions:

1. Should I move this Nuget dll to separate repository? Is this a best practice?
2. Can i somehow configure a task in AzureDevops pipeline in a way that version should be bumped only when there is a change made to that dll?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Yes below is right answear! we modified the pipeline as you suggested and it works! However I will move the nuget to separate repository as it will be used by broader audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Should I move this Nuget dll to separate repository? Is this a best practice?

It depends on your actual application. If the project of this NuGet dll in the solution is independent and not related to other projects. The best practice is to move this Nuget dll to separate repository.

This helps to manage the shared nuget dll.

> 2. Can i somehow configure a task in AzureDevops pipeline in a way that version should be bumped only when there is a change made to that
>    dll?

AFAIK, there is no such task to achieve this. But we could try to modify current pipeline to only build **AspNet Core app project** instead of the **solution**, and create a new pipeline only build the nuget dll project and give the path filter:

[image]

In this case, each time run a build, version of this Nuget is bumbed up only changes were made to that nuget dll project.